# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name (similar posts not helping)

Tags: java, exception, path, package

I  have a java file named `MemoryComparison.java` kept in the folder  `D:\Documents\CodeAnalysis\project_analysis_RG\CodeAnalysis\input\master\Kajari_G`

I am compiling and executing this Java program from the folder
`D:\Documents\CodeAnalysis`

In the Java program `MemoryComparison.java` I have not given any package name.

Now, when I am doing `java input\master\Kajari_G\MemoryComparison`, I am getting the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: input\master\Kajari_G\MemoryComparison (wrong name: MemoryComparison)`

I tried all sorts of package names giving the path of the folder, but nothing worked. I checked some of the similar posts, but still could not figure out when the correct package name would be.

Please help!

Comment: Can I ask if you've compiled it already with `javac MemoryComparison.java`?

Comment: I am compiling as: D:\Documents\CodeAnalysis\project_analysis_RG\CodeAnalysis>javac input\master\Ka
jari_G\MemoryComparison.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already compiled the class, the path where the class file is should be present in the class path.

**No package provided:**
Here if your current directory is `D:\Documents\CodeAnalysis\project_analysis_RG\CodeAnalysis\` and the class file is present in `D:\Documents\CodeAnalysis\project_analysis_RG\CodeAnalysis\input\master\Kajari_G`, this should work - `java -cp input\master\Kajari_G MemoryComparison`

**Package provided (say input.master.Kajari_G):**
Here if your current directory is `D:\Documents\CodeAnalysis\project_analysis_RG\CodeAnalysis\` and the class file is present in `D:\Documents\CodeAnalysis\project_analysis_RG\CodeAnalysis\input\master\Kajari_G`, this should work - `java input.master.Kajari_G.MemoryComparison`

Comment: Can you help me with another thing? When I am running it as: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac input\\master\\"+entity.getName().toString()+"\\"+fileName+".java");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java input.master."+entity.getName().toString()+"."+fileName+" > output\\output1.txt"); The first exec is running fine creating the .class file, but it seems the next exec is not working as no output1.txt is getting created.

Answer (score 0):

You should use package name `input.master.Kajari_G` in your java class to compile like this or go to `Kajari_G directory` to simply compile like `javac MemoryComparison.java`

Answer (score 0):

- Compilation does not require package-like folder structure.
- A class declaring a package needs to be in the corresponding folder structure for it to be discovered and loaded by the classloader at runtime.
- For Example

say you have a class called `Test` with package `com.test`. Now you can comple this class from anywhere but to run this class, it has to be in `com/test` folder AND should be run from outside of folder structure

`java com.test.Test`